# Why constant declaration in function declaration doesn't throw an error?

Tags: javascript, function, constants, declaration, redeclaration

```
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const para = document.querySelector('p');

select.addEventListener('change', setWeather);

function setWeather() {
  const choice = select.value;

  if (choice === 'sunny') {
    para.textContent = 'It is nice and sunny outside today. Wear shorts! Go to the beach, or the park, and get an ice cream.';
  } else if (choice === 'rainy') {
    para.textContent = 'Rain is falling outside; take a rain coat and an umbrella, and don\'t stay out for too long.';
  } else if (choice === 'snowing') {
    para.textContent = 'The snow is coming down — it is freezing! Best to stay in with a cup of hot chocolate, or go build a snowman.';
  } else if (choice === 'overcast') {
    para.textContent = 'It isn\'t raining, but the sky is grey and gloomy; it could turn any minute, so take a rain coat just in case.';
  } else {
    para.textContent = '';
  }
}
```

there's also link from MDN website https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/conditionals

Comment: If you calling a function twice would cause a `const` declaration within to throw an error, then using `const` would be pretty useless.

Comment: "*I believe that `.value` might be change*" - yes, it will. But `choice` is not an alias/reference/pointer to the `.value` property, it is a separate variable and gets initialised with a string value that it will keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the scope of const variable, its life only exists when the function runs, and ends when function completes, hence when the function is called again it is a new variable which is getting assigned the value. You have to learn about scope of variables.

Answer (score 1):

The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the **object's contents (e.g., its properties) can be altered** (for more details, visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Please find below example, just like "const select" , here I have declared a const variable named "car" of type object, and I am able to alter property "model" of "car" object:

```js
const car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
  car.model= "EX60";
  console.log(car);
```

Comment: It's not immutable in case of objects and arrays but for primitives,  if you try changing the value that should ideally throw an error, in his case it's about the scope of variable rather than immutability..

Comment: Please take a look at below link, go to const Description, and see what I am intent to say is correct and explained in this document
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: What you tried to explain is correct, but is irrelevant here, his question is about re assigning a primitive const not an object or an array...